# Close menu that chooses between privilege and badge tracking by clicking anywhere

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page, user-experience

A small but convenient (to me) feature is to let users click anywhere on the page to close the menu that lets users choose between tracking upcoming privileges and badges. Currently, it can only be closed by either **pressing on the gear logo that is rather hard after the popup blocks 75% of it** or **choosing an option**. This suggestion is to let users be able to close that popup without choosing an option by clicking on somewhere blank.

Answer (score 3):

To me, this is a welcome feature, it would be convenient to me as well, often I inadvertently click one of the options listed instead of closing it.  The "Next Badge" and "Change Picture" menus can be closed by clicking anywhere, so I don't see why this shouldn't be implemented.  I hope it will be.